# How to sort a list within a list within a list Python with names and values?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing

Another list indexing question (this one is a bit tricky to me):

So I create a dictionary (collections.defaultdict(list).

```
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields) as cursor :
    for roadname,x,y,bearing,e_id in cursor:
        d[roadname].append([x,y,bearing,e_id])
```

From this dictionnary i append some data in a list. It has multiple levels.

```
for row in d.items():
    #print(row[0][:])  # Name of the streets
    #print(row[1][:])  # List of values : x,y,heading and e_id
    #print(row[1][0][2])#Heading

#East heading
    if 45 <= row[1][0][2] <= 135:
        east_heading.append(row)
        print(str(row[0][:] + ' ==> Heading : East'))
```

The first informations in the list are Street names. Within this list, there is another list that hold several informations (x,y,heading and an empty field(for now). The list looks like this :

```
[('Adams_Street', [[-73.5073589207775, 45.38858418960871, 50.4474983215332, ''], [-73.50783911468335, 45.38868216265172, 50.4474983215332, ''], ('Archie_Street', [[-73.50561268197964, 45.38481501040445, 75.03119659423828, '']]) and so on...
```

The lenght of each sublist (Street names) is different from one another.

I am trying to sort the lists by the X Coordinate (ex:-73.5056...). I can get a reach of all the values with this loop, but I can't figure out how to sort it:

```
for entries in east_heading:
print(entries[1][0][0])
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: That isn't a valid data structure currently. You have the start of a tuple but no end.

Comment: It's not very clear from your question exactly what you want. Do you want to sort each sublist separately, or also the outer list. E.g. in your example, should all of the entries for Adams_Street be sorted, and the entries for Foo_street sorted separately, or do you also want it sorted such that the order of Adams_street and Foo_street in teh outer list matter?

Comment: Sorry, this isn't very easy to describe. Let me try to be clear : Every street has a sublist of values, I need to sort those values for each street. The order in which the street will appear in the other list doesn't matter to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just call the `sort` function on your array item.

You should be able to use [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_sort.asp) as a reference, but for your problem you could do:

```
def sortFun(e):
    return e[0]

for entries in east_heading:
    entries[1].sort(key=sortFun)

print(sort)
```

This changes the order of your sub-arrays based on the lowest x-coordinate to the highest. Use `.sort(reverse=True,key=sortFun)` to change the order of your sub-arrays to highest x-coordinate to lowest.

For example, if I made a usable copy of your data structure

```
east_heading = [('tuple_a', [[4, 5, 7], [1, 2, 3]]),('tuple_b', [[7, 8, 9], [6, 19, 20]])]
```

Then with the procedure set above it should produce this output

```
[('tuple_a', [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 7]]),('tuple_b', [[6, 19, 20],[7, 8, 9]])]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kellan, however when I run this code, it does not sort my data. In fact, if I print out entries[1][0], it returns the whole list with 4 values, and therefore does not sort anything. If, however I print out entries[1][0][0], it prints out only my X coordinate. I can't do this :   return e[0][0] since floats are not subscriptable

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. If this answer really did help then if you could mark it as such that would be great.

Comment: Maxime, are you sure that your data isn't already sorted?

`[('Adams_Street', [[-73.5073589207775, 45.38858418960871, 50.4474983215332, ''], [-73.50783911468335, 45.38868216265172, 50.4474983215332, ''])` is already sorted possibly based on your criteria

Comment: Nevermind, the sorting function worked. It's been a long day, I got confused. Thank you for taking the time Kellan.

Comment: Always glad to help out. Hope your long day becomes shorter!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I totally understand the data you're trying to sort, but if it is something like this

```
l = [('Archie_Street', [[-73.50561268197964, 45.38481501040445, 75.03119659423828, '']]), ('Adams_Street', [[-73.5073589207775, 45.38858418960871, 50.4474983215332, ''], [-73.50783911468335, 45.38868216265172, 50.4474983215332, '']])]
```

and you want to sort by `entry[1][0][0]` then the easiest way I know is:

```
l_sorted = sorted(l, key = lambda x: x[1][0][0])
```

Reference: [Sort a list according to the second element in sublist](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sort-list-according-second-element-sublist/)